# Connecting to Oracle 10g (with the parenthesis bug) DB from VS Dev Server on a 64 bit machine

Tags: visual-studio, oracle10g, 64-bit, webdev.webserver

there's a known bug while connecting to an Oracle 10g database from MS Visual Studio on a 64bit machine because of the parenthesis in "c:\program files (x86)" directory where VS is installed.

This can be overcome by starting VS via:

> "C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

But when debugging a web app using VS Dev. Server, the same problem happens again since VS start the web server using the "WebDev.WebServer40.exe" path which also contains parenthesis.

Is there a workaround that does not include re-installing VS in another directory nor updating Oracle?

Here's the error in sqlnet.log:

> Fatal NI connect error 6413, connecting to:
>
> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=BEQ)(PROGRAM=oracle)(ARGV0=oracleXE)(ARGS='(DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))')))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=**C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft
> Shared\DevServer\10.0\WebDev.WebServer40.exe**)(HOST=PEGASUS)(USER=meno))))
>
> VERSION INFORMATION:    TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 -
> Production